# dictionary error - python

Tags: python, dictionary, nested

Here is my dictionary:

```
  {"draws":{"draw":[{"drawTime":"01-01-2017T22:00:00","drawNo":1771,"results":[3,3,4,9,2,9,1]}]}}
```

I want to get the "results" from this  nested dictionary but an error keeps appearing that the list indices must be integers. Basically I want to get [3,3,4,9,2,9,1]. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is my code:

```
import urllib2
import json
for dt in range (1,31):
    url = 'http://applications.opap.gr/DrawsRestServices/proto/drawDate/%s-01-2017.json'%dt
    json_obj = urllib2.urlopen(url)
    data = json.load(json_obj)
    #num_array = list(data['draws']['draw'])
    data1= data['draws']['draw']
    print data1['results']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You missed a list.

`{"draws":{"draw":[{"drawTime":"01-01-2017T22:00:00","drawNo":1771,"results":[3,3,4,9,2,9,1]}]}}`
Look closely at **"draw"**, its value is a **list** of dicts, so what you need is

`data['draws']['draw'][0]['results']`